# Is there any way to get epoch time from elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, epoch

I have datetime string ('2014-04-30 03:00:00') in Time_ISO field. I have indexed it into elasticsearch with the following config in logstash conf file.

```
date {  
  match => [ "Time_ISO", "ISO8601", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]  
  target => "Time_ISO"  
  locale => "en"  
}
```

According to [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) it will be internally stored as milliseconds-since-the-epoch.

Is there any way to get this epoch time?

Comment: There's an answer to a question that looks exactly like yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351300/5095957

Answer (score 0):

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 1, 
  "script_fields": {
    "now": {
      "script": "new Date().getTime()"
    }
  }
}
```

**new Date().getTime()** will give you time in epoch format