# Have @timestamp in document as epoch-millis when using logstash

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

In a PoC that's being done in our project, we are trying out Logstash instead of our own java based indexing module to push data to ElasticSearch. The incoming json data doesn't have an `@timestamp` field. So when using Logstash, it's adding that field in ISO format. But we already have a specific mapping for that ES index, and it requires us to push the `@timestamp` in epoch-millis format.

I've tried playing with ruby filters to convert the `@timestamp` to epoch-millis, but no luck so far. Is there any way we can ingest records to ES through Logstash, with `@timestamp` being in epoch-millis format?

I'm using logstash 6.5.4 and ES 6.2.2

**Update**: After trying out the suggestion in the answer, my conf file looks like this:

```
input { stdin { } }

filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
            epoch_ts = event.timestamp.time.localtime.strftime('%s').to_i
            event.set( 'epoch', epoch_ts  )
        "
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "myindex"
        script_type => "inline"
        script => 'ctx._source.@timestamp = params.event.get("epoch")'
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

But still it doesn't work. The `@timestamp`value doesn't change at all. Now, I also need to remove that extra field `epoch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a while of searching around the web, I finally gave up on this approach. Instead I forced ES to return the @timestamp in epoch_millis using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349276/can-i-force-es-to-return-dates-in-epoch-millis-format/54419488#54419488) `docvalue_fields` approach.

Answer (score 0):

this ruby code should work for you:

```
ruby {
    code => "
        epoch_ts = event.timestamp.time.localtime.strftime('%s').to_f
        event.set( '@timestamp', epoch_ts  )
    "
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. It throws an error: `Ruby exception occurred: wrong argument type Float (expected LogStash::Timestamp)`. I'm using logstash 6.5.4

Comment: seems we can not change '@timestamp' inside Logstash Filter. So you  need to create epoch field with different name, like just 'timestamp'. Then in ElasticSearch output use script to update '@timestamp':
script => 'ctx._source["@timestamp"] = ctx._source["timestamp"]'
or use ElasticSearch pipeline.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question with your suggestion, but it didn't help. Am I missing something?